# How to skip to next line whilst importing CSV's in Ruby when a certain condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, database, csv

I recently exported CSV's from `sqlite3` database to import them into my `oracle database`. I have written a function in the `seeds.rb` (triggered by running `rake db:seed`) which imports the CSV in the corresponding table.

Whilst importing the CSV's I would like to skip the rows which have a `date` inserted in the column `deleted_at`. I don't want to insert data into the new database which was deleted in the old one.

When the `date` column is empty the value is nil, so in accordance to this logic I did:

```
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export',filename), headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
  class_name = filename_renamed.constantize
  puts class_name
  if row.to_hash['deleted_at'] == nil
      class_name.create!(row.to_hash)
      puts "Insert on table complete "
  end
end
```

This seems to work fine but at the end it always fails,it tries inserting blanks into the database which triggers errors such as:

```
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank,
> Username can't be blank, Password can't be blank, Salt can't be blank
```

which makes sense since my database conform is setup in a way which doesn't allow blank inserts for specific columns.

I read about [skipping blank lines whilst using the CSV.foreach method](https://andrewtimberlake.com/blog/2015/07/skipping-blank-lines-in-ruby-csv-parsing) where the author uses `regex` to ignore empty lines.

How could I manipulate the code which only imports the CSV lines when `"deleted_at" == nil`. Could it be possible with regex?

Is there a better way to go about this error? I get the feeling that the `CSV.foreach` doesn't stop reading lines because of my `if-condition`.

Comment: Keyword [next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) From the docs: "Skips the rest of the block. See control expressions syntax"

Comment: after using the next command i get ´CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n ´ @engineersmnky

Comment: `if row.to_hash['deleted_at'] == nil && row.to_hash['Name'].present?`?

Comment: @Naj not sure how you tried to use next but that error is completely different and has nothing to do with what you have posted here.